# warning: while parsing threads: not well-formed (invalid token) While using gdb

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I debug Linux Arm device with gdbsever version 12 .

Each breakpoint I see

```
 warning: while parsing threads: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

I don't know why do I see that, everything works well.

How can I disable that warning?